# how to make np.where work in this example

Tags: python, numpy

I want the variable b, when the b is between (-2,2) , the output is b; when is beyond the domain (-2 ,2),the output is 0. I try a lot of times. The problem is it can not work continuously, for the first few lines, 0 is output. However, there still some value smaller than- 2, and the output is b itself, it should be 0.

```
for k in range (nz):
    b = xg- nl*z[k]
    c = xg- nt*z[k]
    b = np.array(b)
    c = np.array(c)
    np.where((b > -2)&(b<2) ,b,0)
    np.where(( c >-2) & (c < 2),c,0)
```

Comment: can you provide some input and output?

Comment: What you have looks correct to me, although arguably `(-2 < b) & (b < 2)` would be more readable

Answer (score 0):

What about if you multiply the masking arrays?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(-5,5)
# [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4]

cond = (a>-2)*(a<2)
b = np.where(cond,a,0)
# [ 0  0  0  0 -1  0  1  0  0  0]
```